# Testing Directory exist with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I'm testing `lib/pdf_helper.rb`. So i create `spec/lib` directory. Then I create a file `pdf_helper_spec.rb` in `spec/lib` directory. As I'm testing that pdf folder should be in public folder and here is my code

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'pdf_helper'

    describe "Pdfhelpers" do
        it "Should be in public folder" do
        file = File.new ("#{Rails.root}/public/pdf")
        if File.exist?(file) == 'true'
            puts "Success"
        else
            puts"failed"
        end


    end
  end
```

Am i right?? I'm new on RSpec.

Comment: Don't forget to check the documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html

Answer (score 32):

```
expect(File).not_to exist("#{Rails.root}/public/pdf")
```

Will work for both files and folders.

Answer (score 11):

Pathname also turns out to be fairly readable for this sort of thing.

```
require 'pathname'

# ...

expect(Pathname.new('file.txt')).to exist
expect(Pathname.new('file.txt')).to be_file
expect(Pathname.new('dir')).to be_directory
```

Comment: `Pathname` comes with the wrapping method, so you can replace `Pathname.new('file.txt')` with `Pathname('file.txt')`.

Answer (score 4):

If you're wanting to know if a file is a directory, then you can use the `File.directory?` function.

Answer (score 2):

Researching this myself, and here's what I found:

```
File.directory?("#{Rails.root}/public/pdf").should be true
```

Comment: In the words of the immortal Big Lebowski, "Yeah, well...that's just like...your opinion, man." ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to do something like this:

```
photo_path = photo.path
expect { File.open(photo_path) }.to_not raise_error(Errno::ENOENT)
photo.destroy!
expect { File.open(photo_path) }.to raise_error(Errno::ENOENT)
```

this will also work for directories

Answer (score 0):

```
 expect(File.directory?("#{Rails.root}/public/pdf")).to be true
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this matcher definition somewhere appropriate:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_a_directory do
  match do |dir_path|
    Dir.exist?(dir_path)
  end
end
```

Afterwards you'll be able to use it like this (for example):

```
describe "#{Rails.root}/public/pdf" do
  subject { "#{Rails.root}/public/pdf" }
  it { is_expected.to  be_a_directory }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest option for directories seems to be:

```rb
expect(Dir).to exist(some_path)
```

or

```rb
expect(Dir).not_to exist(some_path)
```